# Uso de classes no grid do Materialize

Tags: grid, materialize

Enquanto estava lendo a documentação do `materialize` vi que para criar um `grid` responsivo eles usam num determinado momento as seguintes classes:

```
<div class="col s2 m4 l3">
```

e posteriormente para concluir a criação do grid usam outra:

```
<div class="col s2 m4 l9">
```

Eu gostaria de saber se alguém sabe o porque usam os valores 13 e 19, pois não encontrei o motivo desse valor na documentação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tela é dividida em 12 fatias. Então para que minha tela seja adaptável temos dois argumentos a serem usados, o primeiro é o tamanho de tela que pode ser:

- s - pequena (*small*)
- m - média (*medium*)
- l - grande (*large*)

E combinado com isso temos o número de fatias (horizontalmente) que seu elemento (no seu caso uma div) vai ocupar.

O código `col s2 m4 l3` indica que a div irá ocupar duas *fatias* do total de 12 na tela pequena, quatro em uma média, e três em uma grande. Sua questão é por que `l3` e depois `l9`, isso não é uma regra ou verdade absoluta, mas por conveniência ou por seu total deve ser 12, assim você não deixa espaços "perdidos" e também não quebra o alinhamento nos itens posteriores, se você ocupou 3 na primeira `div` e 9 na segundo temos um total de 12 fatias ocupadas, ou seja você está aproveitando o máximo de sua tela.

Resumindo: tente fazer com que a soma dos elementos que devem aparecer em um mesmo alinhamento sempre some 12.

Comment: Entendi, então onde eu pensei estar lendo 19 na verdade era L9 de long com 9 ocupações na grid. Muito obrigado pmargreff